# XML Parser from SQLite DB that sends a record to another app Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sockets, xml-parsing

I'm currently developing an android application that uses sockets to connect to a local wifi network and send information to another app which has the role of the server (Client-Server model) My question is this...

What class/methods/tools can i use so i can make a spesific record in the SQLite DB which im using in the apps to create an XML and sent it over from the wifi network?
That might require a DTD also i recon but what's the way to do it? 
All the examples i found are talking for android apps sending xml's to a web server so that's quite diffrent from what im trying to accompolish!

Why i want to transfer XMLs? 
In my opinion it uses less CPU than any other java programming technique like arraylist so it will be smoother for the actual apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there's something built in, but [here](http://mgmblog.com/2009/02/06/export-an-android-sqlite-db-to-an-xml-file-on-the-sd-card/) is a nice example how it can be done.

Comment: Hmm despite the saving in the SD card the transformation from SQLite to XML is helpful thanks! im still puzzled for the transfer & the recieving though...